# Prepending a variable to all items in a bash array

Tags: arrays, bash

```
CURRENTFILENAMES=( "$(ls $LOC -AFl | sed "1 d" |  grep "[^/]$" | awk '{ print $9 }')" )
```

I have written the above code, however it is not behaving as I expect it to in a for-loop, which I wrote as so

```
  for a in "$CURRENTFILENAMES"; do
      CURRENTFILEPATHS=( "${LOC}/${a}" )
  done
```

Which I expected to prepend the value in the variable `LOC` to all of the items in the `CURRENTFILENAMES` array, however it has just prepended it to the beginning of the array, how can I remedy this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `+=` operator for appending into an array:

```
CURRENTFILEPATHS+=( "${LOC}/${a}" )
```

However parsing `ls` output is not advisable, use `find` instead.

---

**EDIT:** Proper way to run this loop:

```
CURRENTFILEPATHS=()
while IFS= read -d '' -r f; do
   CURRENTFILEPATHS+=( "$f" )
done < <(find "$LOC" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0)
```

Comment: This is only giving me the first value of the array now

Comment: What is output of `ls $LOC -AFl | sed "1 d" |  grep "[^/]$" | awk '{ print $9 }'` command?

Comment: see **EDIT** section on how to populate the array.

Comment: running the for-loop just sets CURRENTFILEPATHS to $LOC/file1.txt file2.txt

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using find? I'm not allowed to use that command yet as we haven't covered it

Comment: Well you can use it without loop: `CURRENTFILEPATHS=( $(ls -AFl "$LOC" | sed "1 d" | grep "[^/]$" | awk '{ print $9 }') )` but as I said parsing output of `ls` is error prone.

Comment: Using "CURRENTFILEPATHS=( $(ls -AFl "$LOC" | sed "1 d" | grep "[^/]$" | awk '{ print $9 }') )" just sets CURRENTFILEPATHS to an array of the file names, I want to have all items in the array prepended by $LOC

Comment: ok use: `while read -r f; do CURRENTFILEPATHS+=( "$LOC/$f" ); done < <(ls -AFl "$LOC" | sed "1 d" | grep "[^/]$" | awk '{ print $9 }')`

Comment: I don't really understand how I work, and I don't want to use it unless I fully understand the solution

Comment: what does the "read -r f" condition mean? and why is there redirection used?

Comment: never mind, I understand your solution now, thank you!

Comment: I'm getting an error using your solution, "syntax error near unexpected token <", I don't understand what the syntax error is..

Comment: my first line of code is #!/bin/bash, does this mean I'm using BASH?

Comment: OH, sorry, I didn't notice it was the other bracket!

Comment: never mind, for some reason it only works when I post the loop into the terminal, but when I run the script, it says that there is a syntax error